# WPF - Animation on DataGridRow jumps to wrong row when scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, datatrigger

I have a DataGrid where we display an animation on DataGridRows when a property in the ItemSource is set.

If the height of the DataGrid is enough low to display the VerticalScrollBar, I can scroll up and down and see the animations jump to the wrong rows.

I have made code snippet that reproduce the issue:

- The code shuld be "copy-paste".
- The DataGrid displays a list of Persons.
- If a person's `HasBirthday = true` the corresponding DataGridRow displays the animation.
- The first item in the list has `HasBirthday = true`.

**To reproduce**

1. Notice the first row has the animation running already.
2. Click the second row in the Grid.
3. Scroll down.
4. Some other row should now also have the animation on it.

   Scrolling up and down a couple of times should also display the issue.

- Any explanation why this happens?
- Any suggestions how to fix this?

/BR
Steffe

**XAMl**

```
<Window x:Class="Main.Views.DataGridCustomAnimation"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Main.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    Title="DataGridCustomAnimation" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="DataGridRowSmallStyle">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="26" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid x:Name="grid"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowSmallStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding HasBirthday}" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridRow.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="#ca0516"/>
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="#ca0516"/>
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="#db552c"/>
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.0" Value="#ca0516"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <!-- Note: -->
                                        <!-- Cannot set the Foreground to white with a 'setter' when using an animation. -->
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridRow.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                        From="White"
                                                        To="White" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Grid.Row="2" Height="40" Width="40" Content="Test" Click="Test_Clicked" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Main.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DataGridCustomAnimation.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DataGridCustomAnimation : Window
    {
        public DataGridCustomAnimation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var list = new List<Person>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new Person
                {
                    Name = $"Person {i}"
                });
            }
            list.First().HasBirthday = true;
            grid.ItemsSource = list;
        }

        private void Test_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var hasBirthdays = (grid.ItemsSource as List<Person>).Where(x => x.HasBirthday);
            Console.WriteLine(hasBirthdays.Count());
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool HasBirthday { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any explanation why this happens?

Because of [container recycling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

> Any suggestions how to fix this?

You could disable the container recycling by setting the `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` attached property of the `DataGrid` to `Standard`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid"
          Grid.Row="0"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
```